# Login before using the internet

Tags: networking, firewall

How do you setup a user login page in order to connect to the internet just like the one at McDonalds and Radisson Blu? What kind of setup is that?

We are in school and would like to have that kind of setup so that we can limit the internet usage of our employees.

Any information shared is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: These companies do this by having dedicated network professionals. Your network/systems may or may not support this kind of functionality depending on how it was set up and what it involves. Your best bet is to hire someone, if you can't afford that, then you probably shouldn't be doing it.

Comment: @Aboba: It is not very helpful to dismiss everything with "if you can't afford that". This _is_ a forum dedicated to giving free answers to computing questions, after all; and the OP is just asking about _what_ the described technology is, not for hand-holding their way through setting up one.

Comment: For a small environment you can install a Linux distribution on a reasonable box and then install and configure Squid proxy server to require authentication. It can use simple username/password, Linux users or even Active Directory. Larger environments should have budget for more powerful solutions but Squid is very capable. A "school" should have budget for a complete solution, however...

Comment: It's called a captive portal, [as the answer by grawity states](http://serverfault.com/a/611339/118258).

Answer (score 4):

The website-based login screen is called a [captive portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal). It usually needs to be set up on the gateway/firewall that provides internet access.

Comment: it may also just be a simple "Landing Page"

Comment: Nitpick mode: But what if they just want to use the Internet and not anything web based?

Comment: There's no other way to do it, really. However, many devices (especially mobiles) will check to see if they can reach a particular website, and warn you that you may need to log in to use the internet so it is less of a problem.

Comment: @Hennes: Then 802.1X would work as an alternative, no?

Answer (score 3):

There are dozens, if not hundreds of different ways to approach this issue. It basically depends on what you want and what your budget is... There is hardware, there is software and both have their pros and cons.

Simply google "restrict internet usage" (or similar phrases) and you'll find what you need.

There are a lot of ways to restrict internet usage as well. First of all, you have your mentioned password protection to allow access, but simple software doesn't restrict what type of access, quotas, bandwidth and so forth.

You can also think about combining several systems, like a password protected proxy (with or without quotas) and a packet shaper.

A packet shaper, will for example allow you to give priorities to certain traffic and/or block other traffic (with or without timed schedules). For example, you will want to allow VoIP/conferencing protocols to have full priority and trim down on file sharing (whether p2p or even ftp or http downloads/uploads).

A proxy itself will save you some bandwidth, but the savings you make are highly overrated these days. It used to work a lot better 15 years ago when there were a lot more static web pages. But, that doesn't mean a proxy isn't a good thing to have. It can do a lot more than just save you a bit of bandwidth. You can add access restrictions, quota's, logins, and so forth and give you quite a good bit of monitoring on traffic as well. You can opt for a regular proxy or set up a transparent proxy (which I think is the better option).

The solution you are looking for, like I said before, greatly depends on your budget, the capabilities of your IT department and your current infrastructure. There are a lot of options out there and you don't necessarily have to rely on a package that offers everything you want in 1 product. Obviously you need the expertise, a person to maintain the system and an infrastructure that supports the chosen solution on top of the initial investment.